# How to get the value of checked radio button which were displayed from database thru a heredoc

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button, heredoc

There is no error in this code. This is a query to show question and 4 choices of answer per question. I selected the questions and answers from the database thru a heredoc, displayed the answers as radio button. My question is, when the user selects an answer, how to get the value of the checked answer since I am using heredoc to display the answers.

```
function take_assessment(){

    $query = query("SELECT * FROM assess_questions");
    confirm($query);

while($row = fetch_array($query)) {

  $questions = <<<HEREDOC

<p>{$row['question']}</p>

  <input type="radio" name="{$row['question_id']}" value="A">{$row['A']}<br>
  <input type="radio" name="{$row['question_id']}" value="B">{$row['B']}<br>
  <input type="radio" name="{$row['question_id']}" value="C">{$row['C']}<br>
  <input type="radio" name="{$row['question_id']}" value="D">{$row['D']}<hr>

HEREDOC;

echo $questions;

    }

  }
```

[image]

Comment: What is `query`? Is there some kind of wrapper in play here?

Comment: What exactly is the problem in this code? If you submit the form, there are the distinct values `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` given

Comment: im having a hard time thinking what to do. when the user selects an answer, how to get the value of the selected answer. I know how to get value of radio buttons. My issue here is since they were displayed thru a delimiter, I don't know what to do. Searched everywhere but cant find an answer.

Comment: @Beth Look in the HTML code to see what is the name of the radio input. Then in the server it would be saved in $_POST['name'] location

Comment: What **exactly** is the problem? If the markup is rendered, the value is written there and doesn't care about the "delimiter" (whatever you mean by that)

Comment: By delimiter I meant heredoc, sorry guys. Yeah I know how to get the value of the radio button. My problem is since I used heredoc to display the questions, I dont even know how to submit the values.